# How can i implement a webinar to my PHP website?

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla1.5, webinar

I found some Joomla extension for webinar.

For a website developed in PHP, wordpress or joomla , what all are the prerequisite to add a Webinar feature ?

Flash / Flex is  needed!!

How will i get the live feeds to my website.
Is it same  like live broadcasting of a cricket match?
How it is done?

Comment: This is rather broad. Narrow it down to some specific problem, not "how do I build an entire system".

Comment: Am asking about a feature implementation , if you cant answer it just ignore.

Comment: Marc is right, you haven't given enough information for anyone to be able to answer you. There are tons of ways to serve live video depending on your needs and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why dont you say one way from that tons of ways , that i can implement in a website developed in PHP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign up for http://www.ustream.tv/ and embed it in your site.